# PHP Array not returning the correct columns

Tags: php

I have a query the returns columns from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
I then create an array, use the array in a foreach loop to create another array.

The issue I have is the final array starts at a position 0, producing column SeqID0 but the first column is SeqID1:

```
Array ( [0] => SeqID0 [1] => SeqID1 [2] => SeqID2 [3] => SeqID3 [4] => SeqID4 [5] => SeqID5 [6] => SeqID6 [7] => SeqID7 [8] => SeqID8 [9] => SeqID9 [10] => SeqID10 [11] => SeqID11 [12] => SeqID12 [13] => SeqID13 [14] => SeqID14 [15] => SeqID15 [16] => SeqID16 [17] => SeqID17 [18] => SeqID18 [19] => SeqID19 [20] => SeqID20 [21] => SeqID21 [22] => SeqID22 [23] => SeqID23 [24] => SeqID24 [25] => SeqID25 [26] => SeqID26 [27] => SeqID27 [28] => SeqID28 [29] => SeqID29 [30] => SeqID30 [31] => SeqID31 [32] => SeqID32 [33] => SeqID33 [34] => SeqID34 [35] => SeqID35 [36] => SeqID36 [37] => SeqID37 [38] => SeqID38 [39] => SeqID39 [40] => SeqID40 [41] => SeqID41 [42] => SeqID42 [43] => SeqID43 [44] => SeqID44 [45] => SeqID45 [46] => SeqID46 )
```

How can I make the array start at SeqID1.

This is my code;

```
$strSQLCol = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'NXLHR_Active' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'SeqID%'";

$rsCol = mysqli_query($link,$strSQLCol);                                        

$SeqList = array();

do {
    $SeqList[] = $row;
} while($row = $rsCol->fetch_assoc());

$SeqIDArray = array();
foreach($SeqList as $key => $value) {
    $SeqIDArray[] = 'SeqID' . $key;
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your improved code. Notice I have added a conditional in `foreach`:

```
foreach($SeqList as $key => $value) {
    if (1 > $key) { continue; }
    $SeqIDArray[] = 'SeqID' . $key;
}
```

Comment: Hi @rokas, thanks for your reply which did work, but for whatever reason the "foreach" is not returning the last column. The array result looks like: Array([0]=>SeqID1=>SeqID2 - and so on until - SeqID45=>SeqID46, but is missing SeqID47. Any ideas why this would be. If I do "print_r ($SeqList);" and echo the result of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA its returns all upto and including SeqID47.